# List of logged in users in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to get a list of logged in users in WordPress?

Answer (score 7):

Yes. There is a plugin for that: "WP-OnlineUsers". You can find this plugin here: http://lesterchan.net/portfolio/programming/php/

If you want the PHP code to do the same, just look at the source of this plugin.

Comment: This isn't a link a plugin, it is a link to a list of plugins, and the mentioned plugin is not among them. I know it is 6 years old, but it isn't really an answer either.

Comment: That plugin, by Lester Chan, is also available on the regular WordPress repository as [WP-UserOnline](https://wordpress.org/plugins-wp/wp-useronline/)