# How to create a sort of site-wide group chat with PHP, Javascript & CSS that will work with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, facebook, gmail, chat

Just not sure where to start. I'd like something similar to the chat box on http://www.shadowness.com/ or group chat on Facebook or Gmail.

I can style the css myself, and the javascript no problem. I need some sort of beginning php script to build off of. Where could I find one, or how would I go about making a basic footer chat? It doesn't need any fancy features, just emoticons, and show who's online. I could probably make a chat page, but I have no idea how to get it to work with wordpress logged in users.

Thanks for the help. Would this be something I could realistically achieve in a week or so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at [Comet & PHP: How to use Comet with a PHP Chat System?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190744/comet-php-how-to-use-comet-with-a-php-chat-system) but you should know that there are a number of things you must consider when making a chat system, most importantly the system you use. There are plenty of plugins out there for this that are based on a comet system - here is a good article on the concept: http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start

I would advise going with a plugin to do the heavy lifting, because in my experience you need a lot of time and a lot of effort to implement a chat system like the one you have described.

Comment: Excellent! Any idea how I would go integrating that or this (http://css-tricks.com/chat2/) with wordpress?

Comment: Looks like CSS-Tricks is having  few problems atm, but to integrate it you would need to do a few things. Firstly you need to make sure you have jQuery being loaded, you would then have to include the relevant chat files, and then put the chat code on one of your pages. You would include these files in your footer.php file, and then (if it's a template) pop the code in the chat file, otherwise go to edit the page and paste in the code there. Make sense?

Comment: But how would I go about getting the list of online users to appear in the chat. IN CSS-Tricks script, you login with their script, how would I do the logged in users of my Wordpress site?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802525/list-of-logged-in-users-in-wordpress